# PHP http_build_url() and PECL Install

Tags: php, javascript, php-extension

I downloaded an API that uses this php function http_build_url(). 
Everytime I run my application it says:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function http_build_url()
```

I made a research and found out that I should install pecl_http to run that function.
Now, I installed it into my system, by the way, I used **Windows XP**. I install this one via CMD by goint to my xampp/php folder and running this command:

```
pecl install pecl_http
```

Unfortunately, I can't install this one because it says:

```
ERROR: The DSP pecl_http.dsp does not exist.
```

Is there a work around for this one? or any idea that I would make the http_build_url() run.

Comment: Maybe one of the dlls at http://downloads.php.net/pierre/ will work for you.

Comment: Actually, I already saw that one, but I really don't know what to do with those. Kindly guide me please. Thanks :)

Comment: You need the dll that fits your php version. Place it in the extensions directory of your php installation and enable it via `extension=nameOfTheDll` in your php.ini. I'd start with php_http-5.3-nts-svn20091125-vc6-x86.zip ad if that doesn't work try the other php_http....zip archives.

Comment: @VolkerK Maybe you should submit that as an answer, your suggestion worked for me. It would be helpful for others like myself finding this via Google

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is a work around. If you dont want or just cannot use PECL, then there is a method, mentioned on the php.net comments, which is a alternative method:

```
if (!function_exists('http_build_url'))
{
    define('HTTP_URL_REPLACE', 1);              // Replace every part of the first URL when there's one of the second URL
    define('HTTP_URL_JOIN_PATH', 2);            // Join relative paths
    define('HTTP_URL_JOIN_QUERY', 4);           // Join query strings
    define('HTTP_URL_STRIP_USER', 8);           // Strip any user authentication information
    define('HTTP_URL_STRIP_PASS', 16);          // Strip any password authentication information
    define('HTTP_URL_STRIP_AUTH', 32);          // Strip any authentication information
    define('HTTP_URL_STRIP_PORT', 64);          // Strip explicit port numbers
    define('HTTP_URL_STRIP_PATH', 128);         // Strip complete path
    define('HTTP_URL_STRIP_QUERY', 256);        // Strip query string
    define('HTTP_URL_STRIP_FRAGMENT', 512);     // Strip any fragments (#identifier)
    define('HTTP_URL_STRIP_ALL', 1024);         // Strip anything but scheme and host

    // Build an URL
    // The parts of the second URL will be merged into the first according to the flags argument. 
    // 
    // @param   mixed           (Part(s) of) an URL in form of a string or associative array like parse_url() returns
    // @param   mixed           Same as the first argument
    // @param   int             A bitmask of binary or'ed HTTP_URL constants (Optional)HTTP_URL_REPLACE is the default
    // @param   array           If set, it will be filled with the parts of the composed url like parse_url() would return 
    function http_build_url($url, $parts=array(), $flags=HTTP_URL_REPLACE, &$new_url=false)
    {
        $keys = array('user','pass','port','path','query','fragment');

        // HTTP_URL_STRIP_ALL becomes all the HTTP_URL_STRIP_Xs
        if ($flags & HTTP_URL_STRIP_ALL)
        {
            $flags |= HTTP_URL_STRIP_USER;
            $flags |= HTTP_URL_STRIP_PASS;
            $flags |= HTTP_URL_STRIP_PORT;
            $flags |= HTTP_URL_STRIP_PATH;
            $flags |= HTTP_URL_STRIP_QUERY;
            $flags |= HTTP_URL_STRIP_FRAGMENT;
        }
        // HTTP_URL_STRIP_AUTH becomes HTTP_URL_STRIP_USER and HTTP_URL_STRIP_PASS
        else if ($flags & HTTP_URL_STRIP_AUTH)
        {
            $flags |= HTTP_URL_STRIP_USER;
            $flags |= HTTP_URL_STRIP_PASS;
        }

        // Parse the original URL
        // - Suggestion by Sayed Ahad Abbas
        //   In case you send a parse_url array as input
        $parse_url = !is_array($url) ? parse_url($url) : $url;

        // Scheme and Host are always replaced
        if (isset($parts['scheme']))
            $parse_url['scheme'] = $parts['scheme'];
        if (isset($parts['host']))
            $parse_url['host'] = $parts['host'];

        // (If applicable) Replace the original URL with it's new parts
        if ($flags & HTTP_URL_REPLACE)
        {
            foreach ($keys as $key)
            {
                if (isset($parts[$key]))
                    $parse_url[$key] = $parts[$key];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Join the original URL path with the new path
            if (isset($parts['path']) && ($flags & HTTP_URL_JOIN_PATH))
            {
                if (isset($parse_url['path']))
                    $parse_url['path'] = rtrim(str_replace(basename($parse_url['path']), '', $parse_url['path']), '/') . '/' . ltrim($parts['path'], '/');
                else
                    $parse_url['path'] = $parts['path'];
            }

            // Join the original query string with the new query string
            if (isset($parts['query']) && ($flags & HTTP_URL_JOIN_QUERY))
            {
                if (isset($parse_url['query']))
                    $parse_url['query'] .= '&' . $parts['query'];
                else
                    $parse_url['query'] = $parts['query'];
            }
        }

        // Strips all the applicable sections of the URL
        // Note: Scheme and Host are never stripped
        foreach ($keys as $key)
        {
            if ($flags & (int)constant('HTTP_URL_STRIP_' . strtoupper($key)))
                unset($parse_url[$key]);
        }


        $new_url = $parse_url;

        return 
             ((isset($parse_url['scheme'])) ? $parse_url['scheme'] . '://' : '')
            .((isset($parse_url['user'])) ? $parse_url['user'] . ((isset($parse_url['pass'])) ? ':' . $parse_url['pass'] : '') .'@' : '')
            .((isset($parse_url['host'])) ? $parse_url['host'] : '')
            .((isset($parse_url['port'])) ? ':' . $parse_url['port'] : '')
            .((isset($parse_url['path'])) ? $parse_url['path'] : '')
            .((isset($parse_url['query'])) ? '?' . $parse_url['query'] : '')
            .((isset($parse_url['fragment'])) ? '#' . $parse_url['fragment'] : '')
        ;
    }
}
```

It was mentioned here: http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.http-build-url.php#96335

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as expected in the following case:
`http_build_url('http://localhost/appname/index.php', array('path' => './'))`
The result should be `http://localhost/appname/` but I get `./`. So be careful to test this thoroughly before using it in production!

Comment: It seems that the comments have been cleaned up with the revamp of the PHP website. But thank you for posting this here. Now if there was just on of these libraries for all of the functions in the pecl_http extension then we would be in business.

Comment: Also, there's an error in this at line 49, in case you send a parse_url array as input (which is actually the requirement). So, change line 49 to this and it'll work just fine: `$parse_url = !is_array($url) ?parse_url($url) :$url;`

Comment: Changed it! Thanks Sayed Ahad Abbas :)

Answer (score 10):

Github version https://github.com/jakeasmith/http_build_url/blob/master/src/http_build_url.php

"This simple library provides functionality for http_build_url() to environments without pecl_http. It aims to mimic the functionality of the pecl function in every way and ships with a full suite of tests that have been run against both the original function and the one in this package."

Comment: The package can be installed with composer "jakeasmith/http_build_url": "~0.1.2"